# Не работает select для динамических списков

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть кусок кода в html странице. Задача создать два списка, при выборе значения первого списка - меняется значение второго. Задача тривиальная, но с javascript раньше не работал. Код следующий (набор переменных для второго списка заполняется с помощью python)-

```
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var jq81 = jQuery.noConflict();
      jq81(document).ready(function($){{
      var a = ['test1', 'test2'];
      var b = ['test3', 'test4'];

      jq81("#nodes").change(function() {{
        var parent = jq81(this).val();
        switch(parent){{
          case 'a':
            list(a);
            break;
          case 'b':
            list(b);
            break;
       }}
     }});
     function list(array_list)
     {{
       jq81("#intfs").html(""); //reset child options
       jq81(array_list).each(function (i) {{ //populate child options
          jq81("#intfs").append("<option value=\'"+array_list[i].value+"\'>"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
       }});
      }}
  }});
  </script>
```

и html код -

```
        <select id="nodes" name="nodes">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
     </select>
     <select id="intfs" name="intfs" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
     </select>
```

Фигурные скобки задублированны ( }} ) тк кусок javascript вставлен в python скрипт.

Проблема в том, что второй список всегда пустой, независимо от выбора в первом. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы бы лучше привели уже обработанный питоном код. `var {8} = {9};` это синтаксически неверная конструкция

Comment: заменил на пару примеров, содержимое отличается, но синтаксис тот же

Answer (score 1):

У вас в массиве лежат строки, а вы оттуда хотите достать объекты с пропертями display и value

`var a = ['test1', 'test2'];`

`jq81("#intfs").append("<option value=\'"+array_list[i].value+"\'>"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");`

Почистил немного от мусора, всё вроде работает.

```js
      var jq81 = jQuery.noConflict();
      jq81(document).ready(function($){
      var a = [{value:1,display:'test1'}, {value:2,display:'test2'}];
      var b = ['test3', 'test4'];

      jq81("#nodes").change(function() {
        var parent = jq81(this).val();
        switch(parent){
          case 'a':
            list(a);
            break;
          case 'b':
            list(b);
            break;
       }
     });
     function list(array_list){
       jq81("#intfs").html(""); //reset child options
       jq81(array_list).each(function (i) { //populate child options
          jq81("#intfs").append("<option value=\'"+array_list[i].value+"\'>"+array_list[i].display+"</option>");
       });
      }
  });
```

```html
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <select id="nodes" name="nodes">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
     </select>
     <select id="intfs" name="intfs" onchange="">
     </select>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это действительно работает, на самом деле хотелось бы оставить переменные в виде var b = ['test3', 'test4']; Насколько я понял, тогда надо исправить строчку формирования option value на
 jq81("#intfs").append("<option value=\'"+array_list[i]+"\'>"+"</option>");

Но теперь зависимый список не пустой, он открывается и отображает правильное количество элементов, но все еще пустых))

Comment: понял свою ошибку, ответ на нее уже написали.

Answer (score 1):

У элементов Ваших массивов нет свойств `value` и `display`.

```js
var jq81 = jQuery.noConflict();
jq81(document).ready(function($) {
  var a = ['test1', 'test2'];
  var b = ['test3', 'test4'];

  jq81("#nodes").change(function() {
    var parent = jq81(this).val();
    switch (parent) {
      case 'a':
        list(a);
        break;
      case 'b':
        list(b);
        break;
    }
  });
});

function list(array_list) {
  jq81("#intfs").html(""); //reset child options
  jq81(array_list).each(function(i) {
    //populate child options
    jq81("#intfs").append(
      "<option value=\'" + array_list[i] + "\'>" +
        array_list[i] + "</option>");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="nodes" name="nodes">
        <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
     </select>
<select id="intfs" name="intfs">
     </select>
```